# Dynamic table with array from a select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a `<select>`, and I need that when selecting an `<option>`, update the questions of a table with arrays that are already defined.

```
<select class="form-control form-control-sm" name="est_civ" data-size="10">
    <option value="uno">Primer mes</option>
    <option value="dos">Segundo mes</option>
    <option value="tres">Tercer mes</option>
</select>
```

The arrays only contain the questions and the combo only save "yes" or "no",

This is the arrays in PHP:

```
$uno = array(
    "Empuja los pies contra las manos del examinador?",
    "En posición prono (boca abajo) levnata la cabeza?",
    "Se calma al alzarlo?",
    "Goza del baño?",
    "Se sobresalta con los ruidos?",
    "Una vocalización diferente al llanto?",
    "Sigue con los ojos la luz?",
    "Mira momentaneamente el anillo?",
    "Reacciona al papel sobre la cara con movimientos generalizados?",
    "Se lleva la mano a la boca?"
);
$dos = array(
    "Sostiene la cabeza erecta por varios segundos?",
    "en posición dorsal (boca arriba) patea vigorosamente?",
    "Sonrie?",
    "Reconoce visualmente a la mamá?",
    "Pone atención al sonido de la campanilla?",
    "Busca el sonido del a campanilla?",
    "Sigue los movimientos horizontales del anillo?",
    "Sigue los movimientos verticales del anillo?",
    "Desmuestra movimientos energeticos con los brazos?",
    "Sostiene la varilla que se hala en la mano?"
);
$tres = array(
    "En posición dorsal levanta la cabeza?",
    "En posicion sentado sostiene firmemente la espalda?",
    "Sigue con los ojos a una persona que se mueve?",
    "Responde a la mirada del examinador?",
    "Lenguaje de dos o mas sonidos?",
    "Pone atención  la música?",
    "Sigue los movimientos circulares del anillo en ambas direcciones?",
    "Mira fugazmente de un objeto a otro?",
    "Reacciona al papel sobre la cara voltenando vigorozamente la cabeza?",
    "Juega con sus dedos?"
);
```

This would be the structure of the table and in the `echo uno[0]` is where I want the array to change dynamically

```
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $uno[0]; ?></td>
    <td>
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="CP2001" value="S"><label class="form-check-label">Si</label>
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="CP2001" value="N"><label class="form-check-label">No</label>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $uno[1]; ?></td>
    <td>
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="CP2002" value="S"><label class="form-check-label">Si</label>
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="CP2002" value="N"><label class="form-check-label">No</label>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $uno[2]; ?></td>
    <td>
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="CP2003" value="S"><label class="form-check-label">Si</label>
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="CP2003" value="N"><label class="form-check-label">No</label>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $uno[3]; ?></td>
    <td>
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="CP2004" value="S"><label class="form-check-label">Si</label>
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="CP2004" value="N"><label class="form-check-label">No</label>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $uno[4]; ?></td>
    <td>
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="CP2005" value="S"><label class="form-check-label">Si</label>
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="CP2005" value="N"><label class="form-check-label">No</label>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

I hope you can help me, thank you

Comment: What have you tried? You tagged javascript and jquery, but I don't see any.

Comment: I tried whit jquery, but don't work. try passing the variable from the select, to jquery to process it and return it to php with the array name. But I can't find a way to make it call the array to display the values.

Comment: Well, you’re talking apples and oranges. the arrays are on your server, and the html is in the users browser. So you either have to ask the server for the next values (via form submission or ajax), or you have to add the arrays into the page where your javascript can access them as javascript arrays or objects.  So decide which way you want to go, give it a try, and repost if you run into a problem with the implementation. I’d advise the old fashioned form submit before getting fancy with javascript